# Global emacs style X keybindings (like xbindkeys)

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts

I like using modular components and not relying too heavily of desktop management systems. As such [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeysrc_2) appeals to me.

However, I have a sufficient number of keybindings that I want more complicated keybindings. Explicitly I'd quite like something like [i3's modes](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#binding_modes) ( [emacs's hydra](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Hydra) provides similar features) and emacs style [keychains](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeySequence#key).

Can xbindkeys be made to do this? Is there a similar tool (outside of a window manager itself that supports this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xbindkeys provides for sequences of keys to cause actions, such as this ["combo keys" example](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/xbindkeys.git/tree/xbindkeysrc-combo.scm):

```
This configuration allow combo keys.
 ie Control+z Control+e -> xterm
 Control+z z         -> rxvt
 Control+z Control+g -> quit second mode
```

You will need to use a control file written in *guile*, which is a language based on scheme, so fairly comprehensible to a reader of emacs elisp.

Alternatively, if you just want a sort of *mode change* setup, you can simply program a key to restart xbindkeys with a different configuration file for that mode.

Comment: Nice. I thought I might be able to do stuff with the guile bindings, but on a first glance failed to find any documentation. Looking again I can find this [example file](http://web.archive.org/web/20171026231230/http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeysrc.scm.html). `(define-key-chords)` looks like the function for emacs style key chains here. I guess to get modes I would end up doing a lot of unbinding and rebinding in guile. I wonder f someone has already written some code for this!